# Array circular patern

Tags: modifiers

So ive looked for answers but this is odd, my Rotation scale and location is all applied and fine but when i array my mesh around the axis it becomes smaller and rotates in an unpredictable way. Any ideas why ?[image]

Comment: The scale of the arrayed object may be applied, but how about the scale of the Empty? An object-offset array modifier incrementally and cumulatively  applies the transform of the  target object to the arrayed instances..

Answer (score 1):

So i found the problem. make sure your delta transforms are normal